# What is the best infrastructure for OTT channels like telegram?

Tags: chat, publish-subscribe, ejabberd, channel, telegram

We have a `OTT` application which deliver message to users over `XMPP` protocol. we using `eJabberd` to deliver messages. also we have group chats that user can use them with maximum of 200 users.

Now we want to build channels. some think like `Telegram channels`.
it seems similar application like `Viber` and `Telegram` using different infrastructure for channels.

Now the question is what is the best infrastructure  for channels (server side and client side)?

where is our start point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is many approach you can use to build such system. A tool like ejabberd has been designed to build that type of system. It is scalable and fully extensible through a built in API. This would be a good bet as many OTT services are already built on top of ejabberd.

Comment: thanks for your answer.... but is another solution available?
MUC in ejabberd is not suitable for this.

Comment: You can build OTT services on top of ejabberd MUC, definitely.

Comment: ejabberd MUC not suitable for this purpose.
reason : problem with discussion history of ejabberd. or MUC presence.
https://projects.tigase.org/boards/8/topics/3549

Comment: thanks for your reply but
1. In muc, how many concurrent user can be online?
2. When we have a many users online in a MUC, what will happend with Bandwith?(broadcast presence)
3. How many offline messages can be stored in spool in maximum?
4. How can user receives sent messages, when he was offline?(discussion history problem, what is the maximum history size for a MUC)

thnaks in advanced

Comment: There is plenty of solution and approach for what you need. For users, presence limitation, etc, you can easily solve the issue with change of mod_muc behaviour. This is not standard XMPP and thus not standard ejabberd, but this can be done quite easily. You can use MAM to support large history and let user read messages while he was offline. Your question is about is that possible ? answer is yes.